# Prove for definition $ $ $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{\cos(x)}=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Prove for definition $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\cos(x)}=1$$

Let $\epsilon >0$, $\delta =|\sec^{-1}(\frac{e^2}{4})|+1$

 If $|x|<\delta$ then

$|\frac{1}{\cos(x)}-1|=|\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\cos(x)}|=\frac{|1-\cos(x)|}{|\cos(x)|}\leq\frac{2}{|\cos(x)|}=|\sec(x)|2<2(|\sec^{-1}(\frac{\epsilon^2}{4})|+1)=2|\sec^{-1}(\frac{\epsilon^2}{4})|+2$

I'm stuck here.

How can i prove this?

$2\sec^{-1}(\frac{e^2}{4})+2<\epsilon$

Comment: **HINT**: It's the numerator that gives you control. The denominator is what you want to bound (away from $0$). Do you already "know" that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \cos x = 1$?

Comment: @TedShifrin but my proof is wrong?

Comment: Since your proof falls completely short of getting $<\epsilon$, yes, it's very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use limit law, then

$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{cos(x)} = \frac{1}{\lim_{x \to 0}cos(x)}$ , Then you can focus on the denominator.

Otherwise, you are trying to find some $\delta$ such that

$|\frac{1}{cos(x)} - 1| =  \frac{1}{cos(x)} - 1 < \epsilon$ for all $|x| < \delta$

$\frac{1}{cos(x)}  < 1 + \epsilon \Longrightarrow$ simply let $\delta = \sec^{-1}(1+\epsilon)$ could work. I am not sure whether this is correct...

Answer (score 0):

You want to be able to say that if someone gives you some $\epsilon > 0$ that requires $\left|\frac{1}{\cos(x)} - 1\right| < \epsilon$, you can give some $\delta > 0$ such that this inequality holds for all $|x| < \delta$. Notice that $\left|\frac{1}{\cos(x)} - 1\right| = \left|\frac{1 - \cos(x)}{\cos(x)}\right|$, and

$$
|1 - \cos(x)| \leq \left|\frac{1 - \cos(x)}{\cos(x)}\right| < \epsilon
$$

Notice that if we pick $x=\cos^{-1}(1-\epsilon)$, then $|1 - \cos(x)| = \epsilon$.

So choose $\delta = \cos^{-1}(1-\epsilon)$ and we are done.